# Cannot run "Selected Tests" Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015 I have a bunch of test projects (xunit/nunit). Usually I can just select to run one of them. But that does not seem to be possible anymore. In VS the run Selected Tests is greyed out:

[image]

And I can only choose to run all tests. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Open Test Explorer - (You can do this from the Test/Windows menu)

Select one or more tests in Test Explorer.

The Run/Selected Tests menu option will no longer be greyed out.